# Find Files that Match a Dynamic Pattern

Tags: rust

I want to be able to parse all the files in a directory to find the one with the greatest timestamp that matches a user provided pattern.

I.e. if the user runs

```
$ search /foo/bar/baz.txt
```

and the directory `/foo/bar/` contains files `baz.001.txt`, `baz.002.txt`, and `baz.003.txt`, then the result should be `baz.003.txt`

At the moment I'm constructing a `PathBuf`.
Using that to build a `Regex`.
Then finding all the files in the directory that match the expression.
But it feels like this is a lot of work for a relatively simple problem.

```rust
fn find(foo: &str) -> Result<Vec<String>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut files = vec![];

    let mut path = PathBuf::from(foo);
    let base = path.parent().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
    let file_name = path.file_stem().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
    let extension = path.extension().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
    let pattern = format!("{}\\.\\d{{3}}\\.{}", file_name, extension);
    let expression = Regex::new(&pattern).unwrap();

    let objects: Vec<String> = fs::read_dir(&base)
        .unwrap()
        .map(|entry| {
            entry
                .unwrap()
                .path()
                .file_name()
                .unwrap()
                .to_str()
                .unwrap()
                .to_owned()
        })
        .collect();
    for object in objects.iter() {
        if expression.is_match(object) {
            files.push(String::from(object));
        }
    }

    Ok(files)
}
```

Is there an easier way to take the file path, generate a pattern, and find all the matching files?

Comment: this is bit of a sidebar, but how come rust doesn't have a useful method like `splitext` in python in such a scenario? eg. retrieve both file name and ext in a single call.

Comment: @rv.kvetch it does, except when you are dealing with file names, you are better off using the `Path*` types, since they are more convenient than working directly with a string. For instance, what if your file actually has no extension? If you did a split and expected a second element, you would be screwed.

Comment: @rv.kvetch probably because it's not super useful when always working with full path and you can already get the stem and extension. Same reason why Python's own `pathlib` has foregone `splitext`, and instead has `stem` and `suffix`. If you already have a file name, you can use `str::rsplit_once` (though you probably need a special case for dotfiles). But I'd say that in general it's just not super useful, you often want just the extension, sometimes just the stem, wanting both I don't think I've ever encountered myself. In TFA's case I'd definitely get the `file_name()` and split it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rust is not really a language appropriated for quick and dirty solutions. Instead, it strongly incentivizes elegant solutions, where all corner cases are properly handled. This usually does not lead to extremely short solutions, but you can avoid too much boilerplate relying on external crates that factor a lot of code. Here is what I would do, assuming you don't already have a "library-wide" error.

```rust
fn find(foo: &str) -> Result<Vec<String>, FindError> {
    let path = PathBuf::from(foo);
    let base = path
        .parent()
        .ok_or(FindError::InvalidBaseFile)?
        .to_str()
        .ok_or(FindError::OsStringNotUtf8)?;
    let file_name = path
        .file_stem()
        .ok_or(FindError::InvalidFileName)?
        .to_str()
        .ok_or(FindError::OsStringNotUtf8)?;
    let file_extension = path
        .extension()
        .ok_or(FindError::NoFileExtension)?
        .to_str()
        .ok_or(FindError::OsStringNotUtf8)?;
    let pattern = format!(r"{}\.\d{{3}}\.{}", file_name, file_extension);
    let expression = Regex::new(&pattern)?;
    Ok(
        fs::read_dir(&base)?
            .map(|entry| Ok(
                entry?
                .path()
                .file_name()
                .ok_or(FindError::InvalidFileName)?
                .to_str()
                .ok_or(FindError::OsStringNotUtf8)?
                .to_string()
            ))
            .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, FindError>>()?
            .into_iter()
            .filter(|file_name| expression.is_match(&file_name))
            .collect()
    )
}
```

A simplistic definition of `FindError` could be achieved via the `thiserror` crate:

```rust
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
enum FindError {
    #[error(transparent)]
    RegexError(#[from] regex::Error),
    #[error("File name has no extension")]
    NoFileExtension,
    #[error("Not a valid file name")]
    InvalidFileName,
    #[error("No valid base file")]
    InvalidBaseFile,
    #[error("An OS string is not valid utf-8")]
    OsStringNotUtf8,
    #[error(transparent)]
    IoError(#[from] std::io::Error),
}
```

#### Edit

As pointed out by @Masklinn, you can retrieve the stem and the extension of the file without all that hassle. It results in less-well handled errors (and some corner cases such as a hidden file without extension get handled poorly), but overall less verbose code. For you to chose depending on your needs.

```rust
fn find(foo: &str) -> Result<Vec<String>, FindError> {
    let (file_name, file_extension) = foo
        .rsplit_one('.')
        .ok_or(FindError::NoExtension)?;
  ... // the rest is unchanged
}
```

You probably need to adapt `FindError` too. You can also get rid of the `ok_or` case, and just replace it with a `.unwrap_or((foo, ""))` if you don't really care about it (however this will give surprising results...).

Comment: FWIW `file_name` is the entire final component, so includes the extension. Therefore to get the stem and extension it's simpler to just decode the `file_name` and `rsplit_one`, possibly with a special case for dotfiles but given the use case that seems rather unnecessary.

Comment: Using rawstrings would also makes the regex pattern more readable.

Comment: @Masklinn updated with raw strings (I just copy-pasted that part from the original code). However, not sure why you would decode `file_name` using `rsplit_one`: it's basically what already the `Path` methods do, except that they handle corner cases better than an `rsplit_one`. Also, the variable `file_name` does **not** contain the extension, right? Since it's the result of `file_stem`. Or maybe you meant just calling `path.file_name()`? But still the same question arises: why would you do split that string when `path` already provides the same functionality, with proper error handling?

Comment: sorry confusion as you named the variable `file_name` for the result of `file_stem`.

Comment: I kept the original naming of variables to ease the understand of my rewriting, but I agree the naming is not extremely precise.

Comment: "Or maybe you meant just calling path.file_name()? But still the same question arises: why would you do split that string when path already provides the same functionality, with proper error handling?" because it ends up with simpler code for what is essentially the same error handling: this is a CLI utility so the extremely precise *error reporting* doesn't actually matter.

Comment: I see a point in that; I'll add a variant to my answer with this way to retrieve the stem and the extension.